# Mailboxer - sent and received messages are not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, mailboxer

I am working on implementation of the Mailboxer gem, but I am having issues with displaying messages.
Here's the action where I save sent messages:

```
#MessagesController
  def create 
    # current_user - ID: 253
    # @user - ID: 1
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    send_message = current_user.send_message(@user, params[:message][:body], params[:message][:subject]).conversation
    puts send_message.inspect
    redirect_to messages_url
  end
```

The output of **send_message** is

```
#<Receipt id: nil, receiver_id: 253, receiver_type: "User", notification_id: nil, is_read: true, trashed: false, deleted: false, mailbox_type: "sentbox", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Shouldn't be the **receiver_id** #1?
Also, where are these data stored, in which table?

When I display sent messages (**current_user.mailbox.sentbox**), I don't see there this message that I just sent out.
And when I log in as the user with ID 1, I don't see there the received message neither.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: no id means not persisted, check `send_message.errors`

Comment: That was the issue - there were validation error for missing subject. How to define a model for Mailboxer with own validation rules for subject and body of the message? Thanks.

Comment: over ride the mailboxer model

Comment: an alternative is to override send_message in your model

Answer (score 1):

In you create action, why don't you ensure that `params[:message][:body]` and `params[:message][:subject]` have valid values, and if not, provide a default value.

To answer your question of where the data is stored, your database will have the following tables: receipts, notifications and conversations. notifications has a conversation_id and receipts has a notification_id.